# How to detect the presence of a static member function with certain signature?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I found several questions & answers on SO dealing with detecting at compile time (via SFINAE) whether a given class has a member of certain name, type, or signature. However, I couldn't find one that also applies to *static public* member functions (when pointer-to-member tricks won't work). Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do with private methods?  I assume you want a given signature?

Comment: Yes, I know, and that is a problem.  `class foo { private: static bool bar(); };` do you want to say '`foo` has a `static` method `bar`' or not?

Comment: @Yakk Okay, now I understand. No, I don't want non-public static members. I edited the question to reflect that (the answers were already correct in this sense: they didn't detect non-public members).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following may help: (https://ideone.com/nDlFUE)

```
#include <cstdint>

#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U>                                                   \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static std::uint8_t check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);           \
        template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);               \
    public:                                                                 \
        static                                                              \
        constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t); \
    }
```

Then define a traits:

```
DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_foo, T::foo, void (*)(void));
```

Comment: When I try to use this with gcc 4.8.4, I get:  `error: declaration of ‘class T’
         template<typename T, T> struct helper;`

Comment: @DanielMoodie: Work as expected with [4.8.1](https://godbolt.org/g/RSt6lJ) and [4.8.5](https://godbolt.org/g/8CCqsi). (cannot test with 4.8.4).

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename, typename>
struct has_fun;

template<typename T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct has_fun<T, Ret(Args...)> {
    template<typename U, U> struct Check;

    template<typename U>
    static std::true_type Test(Check<Ret(*)(Args...), &U::fun>*);

    template<typename U>
    static std::false_type Test(...);

    static const bool value = decltype(Test<T>(0))::value;
};
```

It's written for a function called `fun`. Use it like `has_fun<T, int(int, int)>::value`.

Here's another:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename, typename>
struct has_fun;

template<typename T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct has_fun<T, Ret(Args...)> {

    struct No {}; // need a unique type for the second overload
                  // so it doesn't match Ret and give a false positive
    template<typename U>
    static auto Test(int) -> decltype( U::fun(std::declval<Args>()...) );

    template<typename U>
    static No Test(...);

    static const bool value =
        std::is_same<decltype(Test<U>(0)), Ret>{};
};
```

It might be sensible to test whether the return type of the function is convertible to `Ret` instead of checking for exatch match. Use `is_convertible` instead of `is_same` in that case and, at the same time, check that return type is different than `No` (as Yakk [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133683/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-a-static-member-function-with-certain-signature/23133904?noredirect=1#comment35374918_23133904), there are types out there that can be constructed from just about anything).

Comment: You're welcome. I wrote it. I haven't tested it, so there could be errors.

Comment: this actually only detects public static member, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Does conversion on arguements but not return value, and why the `&&` it does nothing?

Comment: @Yakk Right, && is a habit, not needed. The conversion on return type - that's probably the right thing to do, but up to OP. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: That does bring up another amusing corner case:  `std::function<whatever>` `is_convertible` from your `has_fun<whatever>::No`.

Comment: @Yakk `using R = decltype(Test<U>(0)); value = !is_same<R, No>{} && is_convertible<R, Ret>{};` should avoid that, right?

Comment: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"  The second method, last line `Test<U>(0))` should be `Test<T>(0))`

Answer (score 5):

Simply invoke the member function and discard the result in a SFINAE context.  If it succeeds, the method exists.  If it fails, the method does not.

```
// not needed in C++1y
template<class T,class V=void>using enable_if_t=typename enable_if<T,V>::type;

// If the other tests fail, the type T does not have a method `foo` of
// signature Sig.  The class=void parameter is an implementation detail
// that in an industrial quality implementation we would hide in a helper
// template type.
template<class T,class Sig,class=void>struct has_foo:std::false_type{};

// For R(Args...), we attempt to invoke `T::foo` with (Args...), then check
// if we can assign the return value to a variable of type R.
template<class T,class R,class...Args>
struct has_foo<T,R(Args...),
  enable_if_t< // std:: in C++1y
    std::is_convertible<
      decltype( T::foo( std::declval<Args>()... ) ),
      R
    >::value
    && !std::is_same<R, void>::value
  >
>: std::true_type {};
// for `void` return value, we only care if the function can be invoked,
// no convertible test required:
template<class T,class...Args>
struct has_foo<T,void(Args...),
  decltype( void(T::foo( std::declval<Args>()... ) ) )
>: std::true_type {};
```

use:

```
 has_foo< bar, int(int) >::value
```

which checks if `int r = T::foo( 7 )` is a valid expression, and not for exact signature match.

Comment: That's an ugly piece of code you've got there. +1 still :)

Comment: @jrok price of phone coding.  Fixed a typo or two and made it prettier by a touch.

Comment: There is an *"ambiguous partial template specialization"* when `foo`'s return type is `void` (both partial specialization match) - I added a `!std::is_same<R, void>::value` inside the `std::enable_if_t` to correct this, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Comment: @holt What version of compiler and C++?  `void` is not convertible to `void` last time I read the C++ standard definition of `is_convertible`.  In addition, `R=void` should be less specialized than a hard-coded `void`.  Your fix should be good enough, I'm just curious what compiler needs it.  (I thought `is_convertible<void,void>` required regular `void`, which is proposed for C++20).

Comment: @Yakk I tested with clang and gcc, using different versions, and I always get the same result: https://godbolt.org/g/BqLtU2, perhaps I missed something... I only tried for c++14 (`-std=c++14`).

Comment: @Yakk I think the problem is that the template is specialized for the target type (in which case `void` is more specialized than `R`) but not for the target function.

Comment: @holt My in-head compiler gets things wrong sometimes.  Ya, throw the `R` is not `void` requirement in there.  I guess claiming void is convertible to void is a common thing for compilers to say.

Answer (score 0):

Here is demo code (similar to another code snippet in here), except simplified and supplied with example code.

```
#include <iostream>

#define DEFINE_FUNCTION_CHECKER(traitsName, funcName, signature)                                        \
template <typename U> class traitsName                                                                  \
{                                                                                                       \
    template<typename T, T> struct helper;                                                              \
    template<typename T> static std::true_type check(helper<signature, T::funcName>*);                  \
    template<typename T> static std::false_type check(...);                                             \
public:                                                                                                 \
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(check<U>(0))::value;                                         \
};

template <class T>
class Factory
{
public:
    Factory()
    {
        std::cout << "Factory of " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    static void RegisterFactory()
    {
        static Factory<A> factory;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    static Factory<B> factory;
};

DEFINE_FUNCTION_CHECKER(has_RegisterFactory, RegisterFactory, void (*)(void))

template <class T>
void func()
{
    if constexpr (has_RegisterFactory<T>::value)
        T::RegisterFactory();
}

int main()
{
    func<A>();
    func<B>();
}
```

Code will print `Factory of class A`, even thus there exists static class factory for `B` class as well, but it's unused (B's factory constructor never called).