# Calling a static function on a template parameter in C++

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics, static

The following Java code calls the static method `printText(text)` on the generics parameter `T` which represents a derived class of `Printer`. Is it possible to achieve exactly the same behaviour in C++? If yes, how?

```
public class Printer {

   public static void printText(String text) {
      System.out.println(text); 
   }

   public static <T extends Printer>void print(String text) {
      T.printText(text);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Printer.print("Hello World!");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
template <typename T>
void print(const std::string& text) 
{
    T::printText(text);
}
```

To make sure that `Printer` is a base of `T`, you can add this compile-time check to the function:

```
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Printer, T>::value, "T must inherit from Printer");
```

Comment: Or to be more flexible, check if `T` as a static  `printText` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133683/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-a-static-member-function-with-certain-signature

Answer (score 4):

You can do this

```
struct A
{
    static void printMe()
    {
        std::cout << "A print \n";
    }
};

struct B
{
    static void printMe()
    {
        std::cout << "B print \n";
    }
};


template<typename T> void printer()
{
    T::printMe();
}

int main() {

    printer<A>();
    printer<B>();
    return 0;
}
```