# Abstract class as an interface, without the vtable

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I'd like to make an abstract class that defines some methods of a class. Some of these should be implemented by the base class (Base), some should be defined in Base but overwritten by Derived and others should be pure virtual in Base to force definition in Derived.

This is of course what abstract classes are for. However, my application will only ever use the Derived object directly. Because of this, the compiler should know at compile-time exactly which methods are to be used.

Now, because this code will run on a microcontroller with very limited RAM, I'm keen to avoid actually using a virtual class with the vtable this entails. From my testing it seems that the compiler is smart enough to not make a vtable unless it has to, at least in some circumstances. However I've been told to never trust the compiler: is it possible to make this a required condition of compilation?

Here are some code examples:

#### Classes

```
class Base {
  public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {};

    virtual int thisMustBeDefined() = 0;
    virtual int thisCouldBeOverwritten() { return 10; }
    int thisWillBeUsedAsIs() { return 999; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}

    int thisMustBeDefined() { return 11; }

};
```

#### No vtable

This has no vtable and is what I want

```
int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.thisMustBeDefined();
}
```

#### Yes vtable 1

As a result of my sloppy coding, I've mistakenly forced the compiler to use polymorphism and therefore to require a vtable. How can I make this case throw an error?

```
int main() {
  Base * d;
  d = new Derived();
  d->thisMustBeDefined();
}
```

#### Yes vtable 2

Here I've not refered to the class "Base" at any point, so the compiler should know that all the methods are pre-determined at compile time. However it still creates a vtable. This is another example of why I want to be able to detect this with a compile error.

```
int main() {
  Derived * d;
  d = new Derived();
  d->thisMustBeDefined();
}
```

**In other words, I want it to be a compiler error if I write code that results in the compiler producing a vtable for my classes, i.e. uses polymorphism.**

Comment: You're wrong - the moment you use the word virtual you get a vtable for any object of that class; or anything that derives from it

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not: I've looked at the generated object code for all three cases

Comment: Why does `Base` exist if you never use it?  The way to make sure no code is generated to support polymorphism is to have no polymorphism.

Comment: I would take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern. Which would be able to achieve "static polymorphism".

Comment: @MilesBudnek I think that's really the key question. I have various derived classes that have similar / identical parts, but also differences. I thought to put the shared bits in a parent class and the custom bits in the derived class. I also wanted to force myself to write particular methods in the derived clases, defining a template implementation.

Comment: @AlexZywicki That looks fascinating and may be exactly what I need! I'll have a read.

Comment: CRTP was my immediate thought.  You may have to give up forcing yourself to write particular methods.

Comment: CRTP is not a way to reduce code size, unless you have an aggressive optimizing linker like gold or msvc's.  How little ram do you have?! Vtables for tiny classes are tiny.

Comment: An alternative approach is to use `nm` to check the resulting executable (before stripping) to see if it contains to the vtable - and fail the build if it does.  This makes it a link time error, but at least you find it soon after the change.  CRTP feels cleaner though.

Comment: @CharlieB just remember that there is nothing in the C++ standard about vtables, it's just a common compiler mechanism to keep track of what's going on.  All your samples you say are not valid are created with new.  This might be all that's needed, not using new

Comment: I think it's the use of the pointer (or reference) that is the problem, not `new` per-se.  `Derived d, *p=&d; p->ThisMustBeDefined();` might show the problem, or the compiler might be able to optimize it away.  Add in a few layers of function, and you are on to a loser.

Comment: @Yakk 2048 bytes! So 10 methods in a 3 layer deep class structure is 60 bytes which, although small, is not negligible.

Comment: @MartinBonner _"You may have to give up forcing yourself to write particular methods."_ Not necessarily. You can add static checks to the base for their existence in the derived class.

Comment: @MartinBonner I ran though your example Martin and it seems like the compiler works that out fine. Whether it's just because the code is so simple though I don't know.

Comment: Is that 2048 bytes of code space, or RAM?  vtables ought to be going in ROM.  Note that the one thing `virtual` will definitely give you is a vptr.  If you have 32-bit pointers (not an absolute given in such a constrained environment), that's a problem anyway.

Comment: How do we migrate this discussion to [chat]

Comment: @MartinBonner That's RAM. Annoyingly, the avr compiler puts vtables into RAM even though it seems like it obviously shouldn't. See e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43745

Comment: Chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126746/abstract-class-as-an-interface-without-the-vtable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it was already mentioned in the comments you can use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (aka static polymorphism) to avoid creation of a vtable:

```
template <typename Der>
class Base {
  public:
    Base() {}
    ~Base() {};

    int thisMustBeDefined() {
        // Will fail to compile if not declared in Der
        static_cast<Der*>(this)->thisMustBeDefined();
    }
    int thisCouldBeOverwritten() { return 10; }
    int thisWillBeUsedAsIs() { return 999; }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
  public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}

    int thisMustBeDefined() { return 11; }

    // Works since you call Derived directly from main()
    int thisCouldBeOverwritten() { return 20; }

};
```

---

To make compiler errors more readable if a function is not implemented in `Derived` you can use a simple static check like provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23133787/1413395):

```
#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U>                                                   \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static std::uint8_t check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);           \
        template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);               \
    public:                                                                 \
        static                                                              \
        constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t); \
    }

DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(thisMustBeDefined, T::thisMustBeDefined, int(*)(void));
```

and add the static check to the `Base` constructor:

```
Base() {
    static_assert(thisMustBeDefined<Der>::thisMustBeDefined, 
                  "Derived class must implement thisMustBeDefined");
}
```

---

Though one drawback you should consider when working on a small device, and you have more versions of `Derived` at a time is that the code in `Base` will be duplicated for each `Derived` instance.

So you have to decide if what's the more important limitation for your use case.

As @ChrisDrew pointed out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265936/abstract-class-as-an-interface-without-the-vtable/40268070?noredirect=1#comment67797470_40268070), moving the `thisCouldBeOverwritten()` and `thisWillBeUsedAsIs()` functions to another base class that the `Base` template class derives from would facilitate that problem.

Comment: Instead of `int(*)(void)`, you should use `int(T::*)(void)` for the check to be valid. This error could be avoidable with the `is_detected` metafunction and expression sfinae, and won't require a macro.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot THX for fixing.

Comment: To be honest, theat looks awful and more like C than C++ code. It also disallows features C++ is typically used for (and which require vtables). Sometimes it is better to be consequent and use the correct language for a problem. Here OP would be better-off using C from the start. This does not imply not using OOP, but it just means you have full control on what goes on and no hidden overhead.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot [`is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) is experimental though.

Comment: @Olaf I don't know why OP should be using C, especially when he want to do such abstractions.

Comment: @Olaf Awww, c'mon ;)

Comment: Would it help for the templated base class to inherit from a non-templated base? In terms of avoiding duplicate code.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Yes, the common stuff could be moved out to another base class. Any of the _abstract_ functions would still be duplicated though.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Simply because he apparently wants to have full control over the the generated output, i.e. no hidden data-structures. There are good applications for C++, there are good applications for Python and there are good applications for C. A highly restricted device is best served with the latter. - Without much loss of comfort.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Your work-around might generate actually more overhead than a vtable, depending on the actual class structure and code. But hey, it is not my project, so I did not DV, just comment.

Comment: @Olaf Even small devices can be under full control using c++ code, as long you know well what you're doing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Sure, but it cannot exploit C++ features well. Sometimes a different OOP approach is better. And here C++ can cause more trouble (i.e. larger binary, less readable, ...) than good. Without the whole project in view, it is not possible to tell, but sometimes a lean language indeed **is** better. After all, one has not to carefully think about ever design-decission if that generates hidden overhead. And for the "what you are doing" - well, that is **always** the problem, isn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in πάντα ῥεῖ's answer, CRTP is the solution here.
But a correction:
The method `thisMustBeDefined` does not actually require that Derived implements it.

```
int thisMustBeDefined() {
    // Incorrect theory: Will fail to compile if not declared in Der
    static_cast<Der*>(this)->thisMustBeDefined();
}
```

See in godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/x6o1T6jn1

You could use a deleted function to require that a function is defined in a derived class, but note that it ONLY works if the function is used in the program.

```
template <typename Der>
class Base {
  public:
    int thisMustBeDefined() = delete; // Derived class must define this function
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
  public:
    // int thisMustBeDefined() { return 11; } // LINE A
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.thisMustBeDefined(); // LINE B
}

// Compile error will occur if (LINE A does not exist) && (LINE B exists)
```

See in godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/oz9ooe7Yc